# Parse xml file from sdcard

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-sdcard

How to parse xml file from this code. Code is working from URL but what i need to parse xml file from sdcard. 
I add premission to write and read from sdcard.

```
Code :

    menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            final XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
            // looping through all item nodes <item>
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

                map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
                map.put(KEY_COST, "Datum: " + parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));
                map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));
                map.put(KEY_LINK, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINK));
                map.put(KEY_LINK1, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINK1));

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                menuItems.add(map);

            }
```

XMLClass:

```
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
    }

    /**
     * Getting XML DOM element
     * @param XML string
     * */
    public Document getDomElement(String xml){
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
                doc = db.parse(is); 

            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }

            return doc;
    }

    /** Getting node value
      * @param elem element
      */
     public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
         Node child;
         if( elem != null){
             if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                 for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                     if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                         return child.getNodeValue();
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         return "";
     }

     /**
      * Getting node value
      * @param Element node
      * @param key string
      * */
     public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
            NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
            return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
        }
}
```

What i need edit? 
Location of folder on sdcard is "/sdcard/.Folder/".
Can I add that code on XMLClass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What i need edit? Location of folder on sdcard is "/sdcard/.Folder/".
> Can I add that code on XMLClass?

Here is my first idea.

Since your source file is located in mobile phone, you can remove all your work with `HttpClient` because you don't need it. Then you need to read your file and assign its content into String. I recommend for an efficiency to use [StringBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) for instance. For getting path to external storage you should use [Enviroment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html) class that provides proper method.

**Pseudo-code:**

```
public String getXmlFromFile(String filename) {
   StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
   File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
   File xml = new File(root, "pathToYourFile");
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(xml));
   String line = null;
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      buff.append(line).append("\n");
   }
   reader.close();
   return buff.toString();
}
```

And now you have your `XML` String in memory and you can pass it to `getDomElement(String xml)` method.

### Option 2:

Also you can directly assign your `File` into `DocumentBuilder`

**Pseudo-code:**

```
Document doc = null;
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File xmlFile = new File(root, "pathToYourFile");
doc = builder.parse(xmlFile);
return doc;
```

### Note:

You can use as parameter of `parse()` function raw `InputStream` as well.

Comment: Thanks, working with option 1. ( I must add try on XMLClass) :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XmlPullParser` class and `.setInput(bufferedReader)` method to read a file. Path get via `Environment` class.